# What happens if everyone picks the same team in Tetris 99 Team Battle?

Tags: tetris-99

In one of the previous Super Lobby events, Blink told everyone to select blue team, just to see what would happen. But there were 9 people who didn't follow the instructions .

So, I was wondering, what would happen if all 99 people in a Team Battle lobby selected the same colour?

Comment: "It would be the end of the world as we know it."

Answer (score 3):

When everyone picks the same team, **the game reassigns every player randomly to every team**.

This can be tested and verified in a private/password game, even without 99 players, as remaining slots are filled with bots while keeping the same team ratio.
(It is likely that if there weren't 99 human players in that lobby, the 9 people who didn't follow the instructions you spoke about were less than 9 humans, but the game topped up the team when the lobby was not large enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Thats the kind of thing that we will never know until we have 99 switches and make sure we all pick the same team.

My guess is that there is an upper limit, and if you are one of the last ones picking a 'full' team, you will be assigned to a not full one, probably in an order.

Like if a team is full, you are thrown into the red team. If its the red team that is full, it throws to blue.

What backs up my answer would be that if I remember right, in Tetris 99 you have the choice of 4 teams. Blue/Red/Green/Yellow. The streamer asked everyone to pick blue, but 9 people decided to not follow the instructions. And weirdly, they all picked, without knowing eachother, the Red team. That seems weirdly lucky. So that brings me to the conclusion that they did follow the instructions, picked blue, but the game just said no and threw them to red team.

Maybe it even gave a curveball to them, showing them on blue team, but everybody else on red team. But that part we will never know, since none of them are known or streamers.